# Virtual Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vsphere

I have a Virtual Machine that is currently configured with Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard and 8 cores are being allocated to the machine through Vsphere.  (8 virtual sockets and 1 core per socket).  I know the OS only supports 4 cores, so does this mean the other 4 cores are being unused by the OS?

Answer (score 2):

Windows 2008 R2 Standard can use a maximum of 4 CPUs (sockets), each socketed CPU can have multiple cores, and it can use them (up to a maximum of 256 cores total).

References:

- [Windows Server - Sockets, Logical Processors, Symmetric Multi Threading](http://blogs.technet.com/b/matthts/archive/2012/10/14/windows-server-sockets-logical-processors-symmetric-multi-threading.aspx) for a full list.
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2008_R2#Editions

VMWare's assigned CPUs count as actual CPUs (sockets), so Windows 2008 R2 Standard can't/won't use the additional 4 CPUs.

If your version of VMware supports it, assign 4 CPUs with 2 cores each instead, and Windows will see/use 8 logical CPUs.

From VMware:

> VMware multicore virtual CPU support lets you control the number of cores per virtual socket in a virtual machine. This capability lets operating systems with socket restrictions use more of the host CPU's cores, which increases overall performance.

More info from VMware: [Virtual CPU Configuration](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-60/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc%2FGUID-3CDA4DEF-3DE0-4A64-89C7-F31BB77222CB.html&resultof=%22Virtual%22%20%22virtual%22%20%22CPU%22%20%22cpu%22%20%22Configuration%22%20%22configur%22)